# Difference in Stream.reduce with identity and Stream.reduce().orElse() is case of bit wise OR reduction

Tags: java, java-stream, bitwise-or

I tried the below two set of codes and couldn't see any difference in the results. I also tried to go through the implementation of both `reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)` and `reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)` and was not able to note any difference when the accumulator function is bitwise OR.

```
long result1 = myList.stream.reduce((a,b) -> a|b).orElse(0L);
long result2 = myList.stream.reduce(0L,(a,b) -> a|b);
```

Are there any corner cases which would cause a different result or is one better than the other in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the results.

I would however unbox the [`Stream<Long>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) elements into a [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html), so the accumulator won't need to autobox the result(s).

With that, I'd use the second option.

```java
long result = myList.stream()
        .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
        .reduce(0L, (a, b) -> a | b);
```

Comment: So if I am sure that the list won't be a huge one, will the autoboxing have an impact?

Comment: @GauthamM Not enough to care about. Directly, autoboxing is not that slow, but it does generate garbage, so if you don't do this, there is a slight very impact on direct performance, and more frequent GC runs may impact overall performance if CPU is constrained.

Comment: I just tried comparing the time. `mapToLong` was having much better time when compared to the autoboxing in case of huge lists. But it was slower in case of smaller lists (even though the difference is almost negligible). As you mentioned, considering the GC, I too feel that `mapToLong` is a better approach.



Also, just for an additional info for those who are curious - If the list contains a null, the exception stack traces are slightly different with and without `mapToLong` statement.

Comment: Mind that `orElse` can take any fall-back value whereas `reduce` requires an identity value. Only when the intended fall-back is the identity value, it makes no difference.